# Python не видит весь путь и не находит файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Python 3 под Windows 10.
Не получается открыть файл.

```
f = open('text.txt', 'r')
print(f.read())
```

Приходит ошибка "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text.txt'"
Пробую открыть по другому

```
with open('text.txt', encoding='utf8') as tex:
text = text.read()
```

Приходит ошибка "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text.txt'"
Path настроен.
Проверяю директорию файла и скрипта, они лежат в одном месте.

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

Получается - C:\Users\User
Проверяю в свойствах путь к файлу - C:\Users\User\Desktop
Если прописать абсалютный путь, то работает. Но скрипт должен запускаться на разных машинах, по этому нужно использовать относительный, но его не видит или через getcwd получать текущий, но он получается не полным.

Comment: где же в одном месте, если даже в вопросе указаны два разных места!

Comment: Файл со скриптом может лежать в одном месте, а текущая директория может быть совсем другая. В принципе, если вы запускаете скрипт через ярлык, в его свойствах можно указать рабочую директорию.

Comment: `print(os.getcwd()) Получается - C:\Users\User  путь к файлу - C:\Users\User\Desktop`

Comment: Они лежат в одной директории, на рабочем столе. Это даже визуально видно.
Но когда проверяешь через запрос, то выдаёт другой путь. Поэтому не совсем понятно. 
В вопросе указана именно разница.